How to make two leaflet chloropleth maps appear on the same page
I am trying to place two leaflet chloropleth maps on the same HTML page.
Both of the maps work fine on separate pages, but when I put them on the same HTML page, they look fine at first, but when I hover over one of the counties on map1, it is pulling the data from the other map and is changing the chloropleth color to match the other map. Here is my code:
<div id="map-container" class="row justify-content-evenly">
        <div id="map1" class="maps col-4"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="geojson.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          const map1 = L.map('map1').setView([32.74654357428453, -82.25176415866494], 7);

          const tiles1 = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
          }).addTo(map1);

          const info1 = L.control();

          info1.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };

          info1.update = function (props) {
            const contents1 = props ? `<b>${props.name}</b><br />${props.slave} enslaved people` : 'Hover over a county to see the number <br>of enslaved people there. Counties that<br>did not exist until after 1860 were left blank.<br><a href="url">READ MORE ABOUT THIS DATA</a>';
            this._div.innerHTML = `<h4>Enslaved People in<br>Georgia in 1860</h4>${contents1}`;
          };

          info1.addTo(map1);

          function getColor(d1) {
            return d1 > 11000 ? '#2d000d' :
              d1 > 9500 ? '#93002c' :
              d1 > 8000 ? '#cd0029' :
              d1 > 6500  ? '#e62426' :
              d1 > 5000  ? '#fc5735' :
              d1 > 3500  ? '#fd9346' :
              d1 > 2000  ? '#feb655' :
              d1 > 500   ? '#fedb7d' : '#ffeea5';
          }

          function style(feature) {
            return {
              weight: 1,
              opacity: 1,
              color: 'black',
              dashArray: '3',
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
              fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.slave)
            };
          }
          function highlightFeature(e) {
            const layer1 = e.target;

            layer1.setStyle({
              weight: 5,
              color: '#666',
              dashArray: '',
              fillOpacity: 0.7
            });

            layer1.bringToFront();

            info1.update(layer1.feature.properties);
          }

          const geojson1 = L.geoJson(countyData, {
            style,
            onEachFeature
          }).addTo(map1);

          function resetHighlight(e) {
            geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
            info1.update();
          }

          function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map1.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
          }

          function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
              mouseover: highlightFeature,
              mouseout: resetHighlight,
              click: zoomToFeature
            });
          }

          map1.attributionControl.addAttribution('Slave Population Data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


          const legend1 = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

          legend1.onAdd = function (map) {

            const div1 = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
            const grades1 = [0, 500, 2000, 3500, 5000, 6500, 8000, 9500, 11000];
            const labels1 = [];
            let from, to;

            for (let i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++) {
              from = grades1[i];
              to = grades1[i + 1];

              labels1.push(`<i style="background:${getColor(from + 1)}"></i> ${from}${to ? `&ndash;${to}` : '+'}`);
            }

            div1.innerHTML = labels1.join('<br>');
            return div1;
          };

          legend1.addTo(map1);
          
        </script>
        <div id="map" class="maps col-4"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="geojson.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          const map = L.map('map').setView([32.74654357428453, -82.25176415866494], 7);

          const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
          }).addTo(map);

          const info = L.control();

          info.onAdd = function (map) {
            this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
            this.update();
            return this._div;
          };

          info.update = function (props) {
            const contents = props ? `<b>${props.name}</b><br />${props.prison} Black prisoners` : 'Hover over a county to see the number of Black<br>people imprisoned there. Counties that did not exist<br>until after slavery ended in 1865 were left blank.<br><a href="url">READ MORE ABOUT THIS DATA</a>';
            this._div.innerHTML = `<h4>Black Prisoners in Georgia<br>from 1868-1908</h4>${contents}`;
          };

          info.addTo(map);

          function getColor(d) {
            return d > 70 ? '#2d000d' :
              d > 40 ? '#93002c' :
              d > 30 ? '#cd0029' :
              d > 25  ? '#e62426' :
              d > 20  ? '#fc5735' :
              d > 15  ? '#fd9346' :
              d > 10  ? '#feb655' :
              d > 5   ? '#fedb7d' : '#ffeea5';
          }

          function style(feature) {
            return {
              weight: 1,
              opacity: 1,
              color: 'black',
              dashArray: '3',
              fillOpacity: 0.7,
              fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.prison)
            };
          }
          function highlightFeature(e) {
            const layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
              weight: 5,
              color: '#666',
              dashArray: '',
              fillOpacity: 0.7
            });

            layer.bringToFront();

            info.update(layer.feature.properties);
          }

          const geojson = L.geoJson(countyData, {
            style,
            onEachFeature
          }).addTo(map);

          function resetHighlight(e) {
            geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
            info.update();
          }

          function zoomToFeature(e) {
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
          }

          function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
              mouseover: highlightFeature,
              mouseout: resetHighlight,
              click: zoomToFeature
            });
          }

          map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Prison Population Data &copy; <a href="https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/3056/">Ancestry</a>');


          const legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

          legend.onAdd = function (map) {

            const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
            const grades = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 70];
            const labels = [];
            let from, to;

            for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
              from = grades[i];
              to = grades[i + 1];

              labels.push(`<i style="background:${getColor(from + 1)}"></i> ${from}${to ? `&ndash;${to}` : '+'}`);
            }

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
            return div;
          };

          legend.addTo(map);
          
        </script>
      </div>

Does anyone see any obvious errors in my code that would fix the problem. I can also post the link to the website with the maps if it would be helpful to actually see the maps in action!
Thank you so much!
